# Prod Vs Dev : Routes Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having an issue taking my app from dev (Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.8.7, Webrick) to prod (Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.8.7, Passenger). I'm having two issues at the moment which I'm not having any joy resolving. One is with my routes:

```
Started PUT "/clubs/myclub" 

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PUT] "/myclub"):
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `call'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
passenger (3.0.18) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in
```

Execute the following command and I see the route is there:

```
[~/prod/current]# RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake routes | grep clubs
               clubs GET    /clubs(.:format)                          clubs#index
                     POST   /clubs(.:format)                          clubs#create
            new_club GET    /clubs/new(.:format)                      clubs#new
           edit_club GET    /clubs/:id/edit(.:format)                 clubs#edit
                club GET    /clubs/:id(.:format)                      clubs#show
                     PUT    /clubs/:id(.:format)                      clubs#update
                     DELETE /clubs/:id(.:format)                      clubs#destroy
```

When I compare the routes in DEV setup, I don't see any difference.

Second issue I get is:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `pageType=' for #<StaticPage:0x2b228afb8df8>):
  app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:34:in `showbyType'
  app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:22:in `show'
```

Now the funny thing is pageType is not method, it is a variable.

```
@static_page = StaticPage.new
@static_page.pageType = params[:pageType]
```

The last line is number 34. I checked my model for StaticPage and its declared

```
 attr_accessible  :title, :content ,:pageType
```

I don't see any of these issues in dev, just when I'm in prod. The errors strike me like they are the kind I should see in dev but I don't have any issues.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

---Update

Just an update on it. I changed how the assignment was done. I created a method to specifically assign the page type. Looks like so

```
@static_page.set_page_type( params[:pageType])
```

Rails no longer complained however when i hit the view it bombs out

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `pageType' for    #<StaticPage:0x2ba1008d50f0>):
5:   <%= f.inputs do %>
6:     <%= f.input :title %>
7:     <%= f.input :content %>
8:     <%= f.input :pageType , :as => :hidden %>
9: 
10:   <% end %>
```

This leads to believe, im out of synch somehow. "pageType" exists in the DB. It is present in my model class but somehow rails thinks it doesnt exist. Any ideas where i should look or how i should resolve it?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: "Now the funny thing is pageType is not method, it is a variable.", actually, it's a method. `x.what = 3` attempts to invoke the `what=` method on `x`.

Comment: I believe im showing my own ruby ignorance. So it looks like i would have to define my own initiaize. Something like <br/> def initialize(pageType)<br/>@pageType = pageType <br/> this would do the assignment for me. Weird though that i dont see these issues in DEV. I dont really get enough time to get really into it,1-2 hours a week but id rather pick these errors up straight away rather than thinking its working and then try and deploy on my host provider and find out stuff i did weeks ago and is broken. Thanks for the pointer meagar.

Comment: I believe im showing my own ruby ignorance. So it looks like i would have to define my own initiaize. Something like <br/> def initialize(pageType)<br/>@pageType = pageType <br/> this would do the assignment for me. Weird though that i dont see these issues in DEV. I dont really get enough time to get really into it,1-2 hours a week but id rather pick these errors up straight away rather than thinking its working and then try and deploy on my host provider and find out stuff i did weeks ago is broken. Thanks for the pointer meagar. (Last comment timed out, hence the repeat)

Comment: To answer my own question. It was a case sensitivity. In dev mode it never complained about the column being called "pageType", when i moved over to prod which uses postgres,it simply couldnt find the column "pageType". When i renamed everything in my app to use "pagetype" then no more complaints.